# Generate new random distributions based on distribution of my data in R

Tags: r, random, distribution

I have a data set with 27 observations and the associated probability of observation (ranging between 0 and 1) as shown below

```
Data Prob_1 Prob_2 
1      .1     1        
2       0     1          
3       0     1       
4       0    .8    
5      .3    .5         
6      .6    .2
7      .9    .1
8       1     0
9       1     0
10     .6     0
11     .2     0
12     .2    .1 
13     .6    .3
14     .4    .4
15     .1    .5
16     .1    .3
17     .4     0
18     .7     0
19      1     0
20      1    .1
21      1    .4
22     .8    .8
23     .4     1
24     .2     1
25     .1     1
26      0     1
27      0     1
```

I want to generate between 100-250 random samples for prob_1 and prob_2 from these distributions.
I also want to plot them along with the variance band to see how the random sample varies. 
I have tried this so far

```
test_dist = sample(1:27,150,
                   replace=TRUE,
                   prob=c(1,1,1,.8,.5,.2,.1,0,0,0,0,.1,.3,.4,.5,.3,0,0,0,.1,.4,.8,1,1,1,1,1)
                  )
```

Once I have test_dist, I am not sure how to plot it to view the probabilities and the variance band for the new data generated for points 1 to 27.

I am not even sure if this is the best way to generate random sample distributions following the distribution I have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this is what you are looking for.

```
d_out <- tibble(
  Id = 1:500,
  prob_1_sample = sample(d$Prob_1, 500, replace = T),
  prob_2_sample = sample(d$Prob_2, 500, replace = T)
)
```

**Output data**

```
# A tibble: 500 x 3
      Id prob_1_sample prob_2_sample
   <int>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1           0.8           0  
 2     2           1             1  
 3     3           0.8           0.3
 4     4           0.1           0  
 5     5           0.8           0  
 6     6           0.1           0.8
 7     7           0             0  
 8     8           0.6           1  
 9     9           1             1  
10    10           0.6           0.4
# ... with 490 more rows
```

**Input data**

```
structure(list(Prob_1 = c(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1, 1, 
0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.1, 0, 0), Prob_2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")) ->d
```

***Note***: Always use `dput(your_data_frame)` to post your input data.

**tidy format** makes easy to plot using ggplot

```
d_tidy <- d_out %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Id, names_to = "hist_name",values_to = "sample_values")
```

**density plot**

```
d_tidy %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sample_values, group = hist_name, color = hist_name))+
  geom_density()
```

*output*

[image]

**Point range plot** for `mean` and `sd` comparison.

```
d_tidy %>% 
  group_by(hist_name) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(sample_values), SD = sd(sample_values)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(hist_name), y = Mean)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymax = Mean + SD, 
                      ymin = Mean - SD))
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your helpful notes/tips. Very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

**Main Idea**

To generate distribution from existing data, you need to calculate `mean` and `sd` of it,
which you can do as follows.

```
(d_summary <- d %>% select(-Data,) %>% summarise_all(.funs = lst(mean,sd)))
    # A tibble: 1 x 4
  Prob_1_mean Prob_2_mean Prob_1_sd Prob_2_sd
        <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1       0.433       0.463     0.376     0.419
```

and then use those to generate new 150 samples using `rnorm` as below.

```
with(d_summary, tibble(Id = 1:150,
                       prob_1_generated = rnorm(n = 150, mean = Prob_1_mean, sd = Prob_1_sd),
                       prob_2_generated = rnorm(n = 150, mean = Prob_2_mean, sd = Prob_2_sd)
                      )
     )
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     Id prob_1_generated prob_2_generated
  <int>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1           0.0283           0.999 
2     2           0.525            0.447 
3     3           0.247            0.617 
4     4           0.519           -0.0744
5     5           0.817            0.520 
6     6           0.375            0.678
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was looking to actually generate 150 distributions of the sample on hand. Then plot the mean of the 150 distributions along with a variance band.
I apologize if my question was not clear.

Comment: @sck I had to write new answer. let me know your thoughts.